# Can I manually check the value of readyState of a browser?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, readystate

I have a page where RFT (Rational Functional Tester) tells me that readyState is 3 for IE. Visually it looks like the loading of this page finished.

Can I somehow manually check the readyState value for a page in firefox or chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`document.readyState` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.readyState). It will have the value `"complete"` if the page finished loading. The other possible states are `"loading"` (the equivalent of `readyState` 3 for XMLHttpRequest) and `"interactive"`.

If you need to check that value manually, you can use Web Console in Firefox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>) and JavaScript console in Chrome (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), just type `document.readyState` into the JavaScript command line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Marvellous, works like a charm. Is document.readyState equivalent to browser ready. I use this property in RFT (Rational Functional Tester) to check if browser is ready. It seems to me (not sure if I am right that document.readyState is not the same like browser ready.

Comment: There is a `BrowserTestObject` class in RFT (Provides script access to the general browser, which is the HTML Browser TestObject class.) and I can use a method `.getProperty('readyState')` on it. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.rational.test.ft.api.help%2FApiReference%2Fcom%2Frational%2Ftest%2Fft%2Fobject%2Finterfaces%2FIBrowserObject.html